# Power devices max voltage, current, power, speed, etc. .. ratings

Tags: power-electronics, high-voltage, high-frequency, maximum-ratings, high-power

I want to know how to get the real world or the most recent or the reliable information about power devices max ratings in volt, ampere, power, speed .. etc., parameters.

I found this picture that is seem to be reasonable, but I'm also interested if there's a better source or table for similar comparison of power devices.

[image: power devices comparison]

Any ideas for better sources about similar comparisons ? to get the real max ratings about power devices?

For example, the power transistors used in mobiles data/calls towers, they are I think working of a very high frequency speed which is in case of 4G is like 4GHz, am I right ? I'm not sure about my assumption. Or the ones used in the microwave oven magnetron frequency which is 2,450 MHz, I just got that from google. So why these max numbers aren't listed in the comparison in the picture?

Comment: That table is very generic, even if you take one device like "Power MOSFET" there are **HUGE** differences between different models. There is **no point** comparing at such a detailed level, you would get lost in all details. *in case of 4G is like 4GHz, am I right ?* **No**, 4G means "4th generation cellular network" and that can use many frequency bands. Look on Wikipedia what they are. Magnetron ovens (with some exceptions) don't use transistors for the RF.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. **you would get lost in all details** yep that's what I thought ! I just want something that is general for course description not much, just for theoretical explanation. We don't want to list different models .. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this table is pretty accurate (even if technologies have improved) **when considering the parameters** (first column). Here the PowerMOSFET depicted is 500V/200A rated, which make them completely different to an RF "power" mosfet.

When in doubt you can always go look online to electronic component resellers.

Here is a common "High Power" MOSFET 100V/300A  turn-on 36ns / turn-off 86ns  (7$)
[image: power MOSFET]
This one has very similar characteristic to the example of your book (maybe a little faster and a smaller Rdson, but it is relatively close)

And here a "High Power" **RF** MOS 48V/72A ~1GHz  (555$)
[image]

You can already see that obviously the manufacturing process to make the RF transistor very fast and linear is completely different (just by looking at its pricing)

Thus each one has a specific use case and your book table only shows one of the two (it might not consider RF "power" MOS to be power devices, since those are not used in motor control or common power conversion applications but as amplifiers in signal chains).

Comment: You're right it's a huge world and the pricing really distinguish things out !!